# Oracle Apex : How would I pass a field value into a report layout xml?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've created a interactive report that has printing with a report layout customised in shared components (report layouts).

How would I place a field value e.g. :P16_AGE  into the printing page / report layout?

This is what I have in the generic code, which doesn't work with &P16_AGE. and doesn't even work with :APP_USER

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="region-header">
               <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="text text_2 text_0 start">
                  <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="page-header">#PAGE_HEADER#
:APP_USER </fo:inline>
<fo:block font-size="10pt">

Age of person: &P16_AGE.

</fo:block>
               </fo:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible.  The online help for Report Layout says:

```
The report layout is the XSL-FO based definition of the page formatting. All
attributes defining page size, orientation, fonts, styles, etc., are defined
in this section.
The following are valid substitution strings:
#PAGE_HEADER#
#PAGE_HEADERFONT_COLOR#
#PAGE_HEADER_FONT_FAMILY#
#PAGE_HEADER_FONT_SIZE#
#PAGE_HEADER_FONT_WEIGHT#
#PAGE_FOOTER#
#PAGE_FOOTER_FONT_COLOR#
#PAGE_FOOTER_FONT_FAMILY#
#PAGE_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE#
#PAGE_FOOTER_FONT_WEIGHT#
#PAGE_WIDTH#
#PAGE_HEIGHT#
#HEADER_BG_COLOR#
#HEADER_FONT_COLOR#
#HEADER_FONT_FAMILY#
#HEADER_FONT_SIZE#
#HEADER_FONT_WEIGHT#
#BODY_BG_COLOR#
#BODY_FONT_COLOR#
#BODY_FONT_FAMILY#
#BODY_FONT_SIZE#
#BODY_FONT_WEIGHT#
#BORDER_WIDTH#
In order to make the report layout generic, there are additional sub
templates defined that specify the layout for each individual column, column
heading and column width. At runtime, those sub templates are dynamically
assembled and included in the main report layout automatically by
substituting the following strings:
#PRN_TABLE_CELLS#
#PRN_TEMPLATE_BODY_ROW#
#PRN_TEMPLATE_HEADER_ROW#
```

It doesn't mention referencing items.

Comment: Hi Tony. It's a shame. Thank you for this help. I've been trying to figure out a way around this and have messily been able to place >> &P16_NAME. <<into the footer of the printing page. As in, in page designer, under report attributes, under printing, I literally placed it in the footer which worked but doesn't look good @TonyAndrews